# Is possible identify/ignore some reject/fail callback?

Tags: jquery, promise

Since The `jQuery.ajax` api is an extension of  `$.Deferred()` i'm trying to make the ajax calls withe the promise schema with fail and done.

```
$.ajax(..).done(..).fail(..)
```

And use it to make some kind of Api helper.

```
function ApiHelper() {

    ...
    this.get = function (path, data) {
        return ajax('GET', path, data);
    };
}
```

**Problem:**

Currently, I need 2 types of error handling. Some global and some specify.

If theres no specific error, i would like handled by the global fail. else, by the defined one.

I would like to do something like:

```
apiHelper.get('path/to/api').done(function () {
  //all good
})

function globalHandler() {
  //everything goes wrong. notify here.

}    
apiHelper.get('path/to/api').done(function () {
  //all good
}).fail(function () {
  //everything goes wrong., notify here. and ingnore globalHandler.
})
```

Is possible identify if the promise fail, and no one handle it? or ignore some fail callback?

Comment: "with the promise schema of fail and done" - actually the promise schema is `then`, done and fail are jQuery specific methods that sort of exist for legacy reasons.

Comment: This is something promise libaries will gladly do for you by the way (the global error handling). If you're amendable to use something like Bluebird this is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If theres no specific error, i would like handled by the global fail.
>   else, by the defined one.

Note, `.ajaxComplete`, `.ajaxError` appear to be called *after* `.done` or `.fail`.

Try setting flag for handled errors  `handled` ; utilizing <strike>[`.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)</strike> [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
var handled = false;

$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("ajaxSetup:", errorThrown);
        // set , reset `handled` flag here
        handled = true
    }
});
// returns  error
var request = $.post("/echo/jsons/", {
    json: JSON.stringify(["abc"])
});
request.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
});
request.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (!handled) {
        console.log("fail:", errorThrown)
    } else {
        console.log(handled);
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o8gsdyaj/

Comment: Using .ajaxComplete/.ajaxStop/.ajaxError is a good aproach but still can't difference if the request error was previusly handled or not.

Comment: @vmariano `.ajaxComplete` , `.ajaxError` appear to be called _after_ `.done` , `.fail` . Substituted setting global "flag" ,  default `error` handler at `$.ajaxSetup` , which appear to be called _before_ `.done` , `.fail` ; see updated post.

Comment: Thankx @guest271314 I do a similar workarround, oriented to an event, instead of using a global variable. But thanks.