# Determine if jQuery Deferred instance has a fail handler registered

Tags: architecture, jquery-deferred

I have a fail handler that is always attached to a deferred (ajax request). This happens at a global level and it needs to stay. From within this fail handler, I need to know if any other fail handlers were registered. This is probably best illustrated by a simplified example:

```
var GlobalDataClient = {
    makeRequest: function (options) {
        return $.ajax(options)
                .done(this.onSuccess)
                .fail(this.onFail);
    },
    onSuccess: function { /* data formatting, logging, etc */ },
    onFail: function { 
        /* logging, etc */
        if (/* there is no other fail handler */) {
            // notify user there was an error
        }
    },
};
```

Then, within individual modules in my application, I would like to have "local" fail handlers which implicitly suppress the global user notifications:

```
// Let the global fail handler notify the user of any errors
GlobalDataClient.makeRequest({ ... });

// Suppress the global notification simply by defining a fail handler
GlobalDataClient.makeRequest({ ... }).fail( /* show a custom error message */ );
```

From within the global handler, how can I tell if any other fail handlers were registered? I would prefer not to attach any new data on the `options` passed into the data request.

Comment: jQuery deferreds do not have a public API for inquiring what handlers are already attached (and such info is not part of the promise specification).  You will probably need to keep track of whether you've installed a fail handler elsewhere outside of the promise.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212531/is-possible-identify-ignore-some-reject-fail-callback